# Using a MySQL function to find out the maximum record in a table

Tags: mysql

I am using a MySQL function to find out the maximum record in the following table.

#### SQL data:

```
id_  index  Value1  Value2  Value 3  Max_idVal
1    'abc'    5       10     5        5
1    'abc'    0       12     4        5
1    'abc'    0       13     3        5
2    'abc'    4       9      10       8
2    'abc'    8       10     8        8
```

`Max_idVal` is the result returned by the MySQL function. The idea is to go through each row and put the maximum value into the `Max_idVal` field for that row.

Here for `ID_` 1, the `Value1` is the largest value at '5'. That gets assigned to `Max_idVal'. This works the same way for`ID_` 2 and the rest of the rows.

#### SQL function:

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE FUNCTION `fn_get_max` (
        _id INT,
        _index VARCHAR( 30 )
    ) RETURNS INT( 11 ) READS SQL DATA BEGIN DECLARE r INT;

   SELECT Max(value1 )
      INTO r
       FROM Table_name
       WHERE id = _id
       AND index = _index;

   RETURN r;

   END $$
```

#### SQL query:

```
  UPDATE table_name SET max_idval = fn_get_max('1','abc') WHERE id = '1'
```

My problem is that this returns `NULL` rows even though the ID matches a record.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues I can see:

Firstly, the word index is reserved, so in your function you should use `index`.

Secondly, in the update statement provided, your WHERE clause should be `id_ = 1`, not `id = 1`. I have recreated your table and function using the following code:

```
    DELIMITER $$
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `test`.`fn_get_max`$$

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `fn_get_max2`(  _id INT,
    _index VARCHAR( 30 )) RETURNS INT(11)
    BEGIN
       DECLARE r INT;


       SELECT MAX(value1 ) 
       INTO r
       FROM test_table
       WHERE id_ = _id
       AND `INDEX` = _index;
       RETURN r;

    END$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

Then using the following update statement correctly updates max_idval.

```
UPDATE test_table SET max_idval = fn_get_max2('1','abc') WHERE id_ = '1'
```

If this is just a one-off update, you could do it more efficiently with a temporary table (as MySQL doesn't allow tables to join to themselves in an update query):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (id_ INT, maxvalue1 INT);

INSERT INTO tmp (id_, maxvalue1)
SELECT id_, MAX(Value1) AS max_value1
FROM test_table
GROUP BY id_;


UPDATE test_table, tmp  SET test_table.Max_idVal = tmp.maxvalue1
WHERE test_table.id_ = tmp.id_
```

That should update all rows correctly.